# Office Scripts delete empty rows in a table

Tags: office-scripts

I want to delete empty rows in my Table1 using office scripts

`let rowCount = workbook.getTable('Table1').getRowCount(); // Table1`

How can I alter this to delete empty rows in my table1 in office scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the absolute specifics, this should work for you ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let myTable = workbook.getTable("MyTable");
    let tableValues = myTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();

    let rowsToDelete: number[] = [];
    let rowIndex: number = 0;

    tableValues.forEach(row => {
        if (row.join("") == "") {
            rowsToDelete.push(rowIndex);
        }

        rowIndex++;
    });

    for (let index = rowsToDelete.length - 1; index > -1; index--) {
        myTable.deleteRowsAt(rowsToDelete[index]);
    }
}
```

Essentially, what it does is ...

1. Determines all empty rows by joining the values into a string separated by nothing.  If the string that's returns ***is*** nothing, it will consider it empty.
2. It adds each "empty" row to an array which is then used as a final step for the deletion.
3. The deletion works from back to front, meaning, it will start with the last row to delete and move up the array deleting the first row in the table last.  If we did it from top to bottom, it would adjust the row to delete and the 2nd iteration on would delete the wrong row index.